# python os.walk for mobile devices

Tags: python, mobile, device, os.walk

I'm trying to search files on my cellphone using os.walk().
It works perfectly with directories on my computer, but when I'm os.walk()ing on my cellphone (conected to my PC as a media device) it won't show any results.
This is my function:

```
def get_filepaths(directory):
file_paths = []
for root, directories, files in os.walk(directory):
    for filename in files:
        if filename.split(".")[len(filename.split("."))-1] in ("jpg" , "jpeg" , "mp4" , "3gp"):
            filepath = os.path.join(root, filename)
            file_paths.append(filepath)




return file_paths
```

It works great if I give it (r"C:\test"), and doesn't when I give it (r"Computer\PhoneName\Phone").

Thanks!

Comment: Well, the difference in the examples you gave is that the working one used an absolute path, while the failing one used a relative path.  Try using an absolute path for `...\Phone`?

Comment: Under windows everything absolute path starts with a Letter and a :. You can copy the script onto the phone then you do not need a drive-letter.

Comment: How can I define an absolute path to the phone?